# Is there any way to view the local storage of a Windows 8 Store application in debugger?

Tags: windows-8, local-storage, visual-studio-2012

In my Windows 8 store application I keep all data in the local storage and I need to debug the data update. Is there any way to access the storage from Visual Studio 2012 debugger to see what data the application currently works with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why look in the debugger?  You can get the location and then go look in the file using Windows Explorer.  Use the debugger to get the location from

`Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;`

and then open that location in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is tu run:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path);
```

which shows exact path in Output window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for what an application that you didn't write installs you can look in C:\Users[user-name]\AppData\Local\Packages[app-guid].